# How to filer Audit.log based on hostname or addr

Tags: linux, selinux

I have enabled `auditd` to collect logs based on some rules and everything is working nicely. I wonder to know is there anyway to filer type of audit (ex *USER_LOGIN*) based on *addr* or *hostname*?
For example the below log has `addr=192.168.2.59` and do not want to record it in my log but others *addr* need to be recorded

```
type=USER_LOGIN msg=audit(1528028722.288:12745): pid=16121 uid=0 auid=54321 ses=28 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=login id=54321 exe="/                                                                                usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=192.168.2.59 addr=192.168.2.59 terminal=ssh res=success'
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean filter instead of filer?

Comment: oh..sorry for that yes i mean filter